# Show number of users subscribed to each tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, subscriptions

This would be useful, because it helps ensure I get eyeballs on my question and discourages creation of niche or duplicate tags. Whether to choose [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time) or [clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clock) or [clock-synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clock-synchronization) is a question I can answer by looking at how many people actually use the tag.

If I end up with a combination of tags that no answerers are going to look at, I probably need to make some adjustments.

Comment: And the difference to the already shown "x followers" is...?

Comment: @Tom Whoops, didn't realize the `x <number>` was followers, I was assuming that was number of questions.

Comment: Actually, it does look like it's number of questions, not followers.

Comment: Huh? Is says for example "68 followers, 5k questions" (for the feature-request tag) ... is that really ambiguous?

Comment: @Tom Where are you seeing this? I'm editing the question and seeing this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Al6mzY0CpY7EnyCOq_FlHUKROnrv. Those are the number of questions filed under each tag, not the number of followers, AFAICT.

Comment: And what do you see when you __don't__ edit the question and just hover tags here?

Comment: Ah, ok cool, I see it now. So the workflow is: post the question with some provisional set of tags, then hover them to find out how many followers they have, then edit->repeat until you're happy with the number of followers.

Comment: No, the workflow is: post the tags which belongs to the question. If you're not happy with the amount of followers, then either wait for the answer a bit longer or don't post the question.

Comment: Ok, I'll make sure to go back in time and not post the question once I find out I'm not happy with the number of followers.

Answer (score 4):

Not needed as feature already exists and if implemented as requested during post creation may actually encourage undesired behavior of tagging for exposure and not for content of the question.

Information is already shown when you hover over the tag with "X follower, Y questions" tooltip on existing questions. So if you plan to ask question and decided to research what tags would be useful in advance you already have that information available. It is also fine to re-tag questions if you found more tags more fitting to content of the question.

For people who are not planning careful tagging showing such information is unlikely to have much impact.

Note that adding correct language tag will give question decent exposure for most posts, and minor tagging issues will likely be corrected with edits if necessary.